# What data structure should I use for implementing least-expiry-time-remaining-next kind of scheduling

Tags: java, data-structures, queue, message-queue, priority-queue

I am going to get items of specific types. Each type has expiry duration associated with it. Each item is held for the duration specified as expiry duration associated with its type before processing is continued on it.

For example, Type1 items expire after 10 seconds, whereas Type2 items expire after 5 seconds. Now consider Type1 item1 comes at time 1. So it should be executed at time 11. Now consider I get Type2 item2 at time 2. So it should be executed at time 7. Now consider I get another Type2 item3 at time 3. So it should be executed at time 8. So final execution order is

- item2 at time 7
- item3 at time 8
- item1 at time 11

What data structure I should use to emulate this behaviour? Primarily it looks like priority queue which always keeps item to process next at its head. Is there any ready made queue server which automates this. I have extensively used kafka but it does not seem to serve this purpose well. Is there any other option left? Or should I opt for plain Java priority queues? Or should I look for something absolutely different approach from queues?

**Update**

1. Forgot to mention that I may have large number of types.

Comment: What don't you like about a priority queue? You could also maybe use a `TreeMap<Instant, Item>` that holds execution time / item (assuming no two items execute at the same time)?

Comment: Do you want to store those types for future use? or you just want to execute them after given time period? If later is your requirement, I will suggest to go for 'Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()' and then submit the tasks with your required time delay.

Comment: Did you look at DelayQueue?

Comment: @assylias TreeMap sounds good, but can't guarantee unique execution time...guessing workaround...

Comment: @bob DelayQueue seems to be the thing.

Comment: There are also some messaging servers that support a delayed message delivery pattern,  ActiveMQ and RabbitMQ come to mind but I am a bit rusty.  Will leave the research to you to see if its applicable for your environment - ex:  http://activemq.apache.org/delay-and-schedule-message-delivery.html

Answer (score 0):

Use a [DelayQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/DelayQueue.html) to solve this exact use-case

Answer (score 0):

You are right that Kafka does not lend itself well to this in terms of out of the box implementation.

Message order is retained in partition so that could keep the arrival order which would be timestamped (you can add this as a field as well). In terms of implementing priority it should not be too hard to do this with the basics provided above.

Queuing technologies tend to implement message delivery services whereas your use case is more processing oriented. Maybe look at some of the processing frameworks like Apache Spark or Apache Storm.